# Type Erasure for objects containing a std::tuple in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets say I have a generic class Container that contains any type of tuple, and has a function `template<typename T> T& get<T>();` that returns a reference to the element in the tuple. My very simple implementation looks like this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class Container
{
    std::tuple<Ts...> contents;

    public:
    Container(const Ts&... ts) : contents(ts...) {}

    template <typename T>
    T& get()
    {
        //TypeIndex is some meta-programming struct to find index of T in Ts
        return std::get<TypeIndex<T, Ts...>::value>(contents);
    }
};
```

Are there any good type erasure techniques to turn Container into a regular class without altering the get function signature? As in calling `get<T>()` without knowing the tuples full type list? Something like this:

```
Struct A { int x; }
Struct B { int y; }
Struct C { int z; }

int main()
{
    Container container(A(), B()); //Underlying storage is a std::tuple<A, B>

    A& a = container.get<A>(); //Doesn't know the tuples type list but assumes A is in there.

    C& c = container.get<C>(); //C isn't in the tuples type list, crash program, which would be correct behavior.

}
```

`boost::any` is the usual go-to solution for these types of problems, but doesn't solve this particular problem because I would have to know the actual type of the underlying tuple to cast. Like if I tried to use it in the example above I would do `boost::any_cast<std::tuple<A, B>>` to get A, or B which isn't any use to me because I'm purposely trying to hide the tuple type list.

**Edit:** full definition of TypeIndex.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct TypeIndex;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct TypeIndex<T, T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct TypeIndex<T, U, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + TypeIndex<T, Ts...>::value> {};
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming `TypeIndex` is a function defined by you? Is it `constexpr`?

Comment: Yes TypeIndex is a struct I defined that derives from `std::intergral_constant`, that gets the index of a type in a type list, its a helper struct for `std::get<N>();`

Comment: So if it's `constexpr` then can't you try to `std::enable_if`on the `get()` function? Also, how does your `TypeIndex` handle `std::tuple<int, int>`? (Edit: I said function in the previous comment, I meant struct.)

Comment: For std::tuple<int, int> it would return the first int in the list, and wouldn't be able to get the second one, which is ok in my situation because the tuple is assumed to have a unique list.

Comment: Then can't you use `std::enable_if` to turn the `template <typename T> T& get()` into a function that fails to compile if you call with an invalid type? (See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if )

Comment: What do you mean try `std::enable_if` on the get function? The attempts I've made at trying to implement a regular Container uses the `boost::any` method where it uses a base placeholder class, and then a templated holder class but I still run into the problem where I have to know the full typelist of the tuple if I wanted to cast to get any element from the tuple.

Comment: If you post the entire definition of `TypeIndex` it might be easier to make this clear.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hand written `TypeIndex<T, Ts...>::value` you can use `typeid(T)::hash_code()` and store data in a `std::unordered_map<size_t, boost::any>`.

`std::tuple` does not store information about underlying types. That information is encoded in tuple's type. So if your `get` method can't know the type of the tuple, then it can't get offset in it where the value is stored. So you have to revert to dynamic methods and having a map is the simpliest one.

Comment: Your suggestion turns a compile time construct into a runtime construct, likely not what OP wanted? Though I don't know what the OP intended.

Comment: OP wants a container with polymorphism. We have static and dynamic polymorphism in C++. OP asked to turn Container in-to a usual class, not template. So we have to use dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: See my answer, it seems to be doing this at compile time.

Comment: In your answer Container is still a template and has a different type depending on stored values. So tuple type is not erased.

Comment: This is the right way to go about this -- I misread the OP's post. :)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more efficient solution than the ones proposed so far is to use `std::tuple` as the actual underlying storage, thus avoiding use of `any` or `unordered_map`

If we use the classic type-erasure pattern, we only need one dynamic allocation (plus whatever is required to copy the actual objects), or zero if you implement small buffer optimization.

We start by defining a base interface to access an element by type.

```
struct base
{
    virtual ~base() {}

    virtual void * get( std::type_info const & ) = 0;
};
```

We use `void*` instead of `any` to return a reference to the object, thus avoiding a copy and possibly a memory allocation.

The actual storage class is derived from `base`, and templated on the arguments it can contain:

```
template<class ... Ts>
struct impl : base
{
    template<class ... Us>
    impl(Us && ... us) : data_(std::forward<Us>(us) ... ) 
    {
        //Maybe check for duplicated types and throw.
    }

    virtual void * get( std::type_info const & ti ) 
    {
        return get_helper( ti, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>() );
    }

    template<std::size_t ... Indices>
    void* get_helper( std::type_info const & ti, std::index_sequence<Indices...> )
    {
        //If you know that only one element of a certain type is available, you can refactor this to avoid comparing all the type_infos
        const bool valid[] = { (ti == typeid(Ts)) ... };

        const std::size_t c = std::count( std::begin(valid), std::end(valid), true );
        if ( c != 1 )
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(""); // something here
        }

        // Pack the addresses of all the elements in an array
        void * result[] = { static_cast<void*>(& std::get<Indices>(data_) ) ... };

        // Get the index of the element we want
        const int which = std::find( std::begin(valid), std::end(valid), true ) - std::begin(valid);

        return result[which];
    }

    std::tuple<Ts ... > data_;
};
```

Now we only have to wrap this in a type-safe wrapper:

```
class any_tuple
{
public:
     any_tuple() = default; // allow empty state

     template<class ... Us>
     any_tuple(Us && ... us) :
            m_( new impl< std::remove_reference_t< std::remove_cv_t<Us> > ... >( std::forward<Us>(us) ... ) )
       {}

     template<class T>
     T& get()
     {
        if ( !m_ )
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(""); // something
        }
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>( m_->get( typeid(T) ) );
     }

     template<class T>
     const T& get() const
     {
         return const_cast<any_tuple&>(*this).get<T>();
     }

     bool valid() const { return bool(m_); }

 private:
     std::unique_ptr< base > m_; //Possibly use small buffer optimization
 };
```

Check it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6885ccdeb5fb966).

This can be extended further in many ways, for instance you can add a constructor that takes an actual tuple, you can access by index and pack the value in a `std::any`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using `boost::any`, you could use a `vector` or `unordered_map` of them. Here's a version implemented with `unordered_map`:

```
class Container
{
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    Container(std::tuple<Ts...>&& t)
    {
        tuple_assign(std::move(t), data, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
    }

    template<typename T>
    T get()
    {
        auto it = data.find(typeid(T));

        if(it == data.cend()) {
            throw boost::bad_any_cast{};
        } else {
            return boost::any_cast<T>(it->second);
        }
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, boost::any> data;
};
```

And then you could write almost as in your request. I changed the constructor to accept a tuple to avoid a host of sfinae code to prevent overridding copy/move constructors, but you can do this if you so wish.

```
Container c(std::make_tuple(1, 1.5, A{42}));

try {
    std::cout << "int: " << c.get<int>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "double: " << c.get<double>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "A: " << c.get<A>().val << '\n';
    c.get<A&>().val = 0;
    std::cout << "A: " << c.get<A>().val << '\n';
    std::cout << "B: " << c.get<B>().val << '\n'; // error
} catch (boost::bad_any_cast const& ex) {
    std::cout << "exception: " << ex.what() << '\n';
}
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lSfXNvsbkz7XNR10)

You could also instruct your `Container` to commit `std::terminate()` instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? This fits the interface as requested.

Comment: I'm not sure, my code base requires a tuple right now, but this method is nice fall back if there is no solution possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

struct tuple_base {
    virtual ~tuple_base() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct leaf : virtual tuple_base {
    leaf(T const & t) : value(t) {}

    virtual ~leaf() {}

    T value;
};

template <typename ... T>
struct tuple : public leaf<T> ... {
    template <typename ... U>
    tuple(U && ... u) : leaf<T>{static_cast<U&&>(u)} ... {}
};

struct container {  
    tuple_base* erased_value;

    template <typename T>
    T & get() {
        return dynamic_cast<leaf<T>*>(erased_value)->value;
    }
};

int main() {
    container c{new tuple<int, float, char>{1, 1.23f, 'c'}};

    std::cout << c.get<float>() << std::endl;
}
```

The key is that you must know more information about the structure of the tuple type.  It is not possible to extract information from a type erased arbitrary tuple implementation using only a single type which it contains.  This is more of a proof of concept, and you would probably be better off using something else, though it is the solution to what you asked.

Comment: I don't think you need `virtual` to implement this.

Comment: use `= default` for destructor. This has some advantages, one of it being that is makes the type trivially destructible if applicable.

Comment: Because I wrote this in 3 minutes.  As I said, it's a proof of concept... if someone really wants to use this for something, obviously it would need to be cleaned up

Comment: I suppose I'll clean it up for everybody!

Comment: @pat then please do, because this is an otherwise nice solution.